# Reference second table in Outlook Message

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I pull data from a table in the body of e-mail with the below code.

My emails have 3 tables. I want to take data on the second table.

How can I address the second table?

```
Option Explicit
Sub impOutlookTable()
' point to the desired email
Const strMail As String = "xxx@xxxxx.com"
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oMapi As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem

On Error Resume Next
Set oApp = GetObject(, "OUTLOOK.APPLICATION")
    If (oApp Is Nothing) Then Set oApp = CreateObject("OUTLOOK.APPLICATION")
On Error GoTo 0

Set oMapi = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(strMail).Folders("Inbox").Folders("AMEC-DCC -DS- TRANSMITTAL")
Set oMail = oMapi.Items(oMapi.Items.Count)

' get html table from email object
Dim oHTML As MSHTML.HTMLDocument: Set oHTML = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim oElColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
With oHTML
    .Body.innerHTML = oMail.HTMLBody
    Set oElColl = .getElementsByTagName("table")
End With

'import in Excel
Dim x As Long, y As Long

For x = 0 To oElColl(0).rows.Length - 1
    For y = 0 To oElColl(0).rows(x).Cells.Length - 1
        Range("A1").Offset(x, y).Value = oElColl(0).rows(x).Cells(y).innerText
    Next y
Next x

Set oApp = Nothing
Set oMapi = Nothing
Set oMail = Nothing
Set oHTML = Nothing
Set oElColl = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: use (1) instead of (0) when referencing the collection, oElColl

Comment: Thanks for your kind help.It worked.

Answer (score 0):

[Article on collection use](http://analystcave.com/vba-collection/)

use (1) instead of (0) when referencing the collection, oElColl

Comment: this code is working only for last e-mail in the folder.How can I use this code for all e-mail, making loop ?

Comment: do some reading on loops, and loop oMapi.Items rather than setting to the last one as `Set oMail = oMapi.Items(oMapi.Items.Count)` does.

Comment: No, I was new to VBA to, when I started, then I read.  I've told you what to read.